# How to import one xslt file into another xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using xslt 1.0 and I want to import one xslt file into another xslt file.

below is the example :

A.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       version="1.0">
          <xsl:template match="/">


             <header>
                <UserId>
                   <xsl:value-of select="'user1'" />
               </UserId>
               <UserPaassword>
                  <xsl:value-of select="'1234'" />
              </UserPaassword>
             </header>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

B.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       version="1.0">
         <xsl:template match="/">
             <userData>
                <xsl:import href="A.xsl"/>
                  <body>
                     <UserAddress>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'India'" />
                     </UserAddress>
                     <UserPhoneNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'123456789'" />
                     </UserPhoneNumber>
                  </body>
              </userData>
         </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the final output xsl should be like below

output.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <userData>
        <header>
            <UserId>
                <xsl:value-of select="'user1'" />
            </UserId>
            <UserPaassword>
                <xsl:value-of select="'1234'" />
            </UserPaassword>
        </header>
        <body>
            <UserAddress>
                <xsl:value-of select="'India'" />
            </UserAddress>
            <UserPhoneNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="'123456789'" />
            </UserPhoneNumber>
        </body>
      </userData>
  </xsl:template>
```

```
I tried with the import statement but xsl:import is not allowed into xsl:template.
```

Please help me regarding to this.

thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already answered your own question. `xsl:import` is not allowed inside an `xsl:template`, so what you are currently trying will not work. When you use `xsl:import` the XSLT processor replaces it with the contents of the stylesheet named in the href attribute, so in your case, you would have ended up with XSLT like this...

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
         <userData>
              <xsl:template match="/">
                  <header>
```

It is also worth pointing out that the XSLT processor will not actually change the physical file `b.xml` here, nor it is creating a new physical file `output.xsl`. This import is only being applied whilst the processing is running. The new XSLT only really exists in memory.

You haven't exactly said what you are trying to achieve. But it sounds like you need to read up on the `xsl:apply-imports` here. Imported templates have a lower precedence that ones in the main template, so you can use `xsl:apply-imports` to apply such templates in the imported one.

As a starter, change your `B.xml` file to look like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:import href="A.xml"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <userData>
      <xsl:apply-imports />
      <body>
        <UserAddress>
          <xsl:value-of select="'India'" />
        </UserAddress>
        <UserPhoneNumber>
          <xsl:value-of select="'123456789'" />
        </UserPhoneNumber>
      </body>
    </userData>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, when `xsl:apply-imports` is used in the example over, it will actually match the main template in the imported `a.xml` file.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Combining-Stylesheets for detailed information.

Comment: I tired following code

     <xsl:variable name="filePath" select="concat(Systemprop:getProperty('docRootPath'),'/xsl/file/A.xsl')" />
where docrootPath = c:/test/testdata

but its is giving error : Element type "xsl:variable" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

I also tried with

but its giving me :Had IO Exception with stylesheet file. Please suggest .